# flot hover instead of click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Im facing a problem right now: I've got flot chart and when it's clicked it shows a modular window with data.

I need to do the same stuff, but instead of click event, i need to do this on hover. Docs at github only shows how to do that on click event. Im stumped with doing the same thing on hover. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The event for hover on flot is called "plothover", so bind that event to the container of the diagram and set a callback, like so:

```
$(diagramContainer).bind("plothover",function(event, pos, item) {
   // event holds the js event, pos holds the (x,y) coordinate, item holds the 
   // closest data item to the event
});
```

The item usualy has enough information for you to add a tooltip to the data item, like the attributes item.pageX and item.pageY, the values are saved on the attribute item.datapoint, you can find the series configuration accessing the item.series attribute (like item.series.color).

Answer (score 0):

Change your function event with hover

```
$(function (){
   $("#yourID").hover(function (){
     //your code goes here 
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements.

```
$(function (){
   $("#yourID").hover(OnmouseoverFunction, Onmouseoutfunction);
})

function OnmouseoverFunction()
{
 //on mouse over code
}

function Onmouseoutfunction()
{
 //on mouse outcode
}
```